# I want to make a tree-questions and I do this and it work , but I want to know if there is an easier way to do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

this is the tree-questions , it's a simple sample for what I want to do and in the bottom is the paragraph which saved the radio buttons value

```js
function radioFunc(answer) {
  document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML = answer;
}


function question1() {
  var myanswer = document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML;
  if (myanswer === "yes") {
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "block";
  } else if (myanswer === "no") {
    alert("I'm sorry , You're not Ramy!");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <p>Are you 18?</p>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes" onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="no" onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">No<br><br>
    <input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="question1()">
  </form>
</div>
<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
  <p>Are you over in college?</p>
  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes" onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="answer" value="no" onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">No<br><br>
    <input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="question2()">
  </form>
</div>

<p id="radio" style="display: none;"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic looks fine but you can use **single function question()** instead of making so many functions question1(), question2() this will make your javascript code **looks more simple and easier** (assuming if the answer is no in any of the question you are giving message "I'm sorry , You're not Ramy!")

```
<div id="div1">
    <p>Are you 18?</p>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes" 
        onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="no" 
        onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">No<br><br>
        <input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="question()">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="div2" style="display: none;">
    <p>Are you over in college?</p>
    <form>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="yes" 
          onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">Yes<br>
        <input type="radio" name="answer" value="no" 
          onclick="radioFunc(this.value)">No<br><br>
        <input type="button" value="confirm" onclick="question()">
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="div3" style="display: none;">
        <h1>Hello Ramsey<h1>
    </div>

<p id="radio" style="display: none;"></p>
```

javascript code:

```
function radioFunc(answer){
    document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML = answer;
}

var count = 1;
var quesToHide='';
var quesToShow='';
function question() {
    var myanswer = document.getElementById("radio").innerHTML;
    if (myanswer === "yes") {
        quesToHide ="div"+count;
        count++;
        quesToShow ="div"+count;
        document.getElementById(quesToHide).style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById(quesToShow).style.display = "block";
    } else if(myanswer === "no"){
        alert("I'm sorry , You're not Ramy!");
    }
}
```